# Ошибка SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax в rpatool

Tags: python, syntax

Питон 2.7.15 ругается

Я не особо шарю в питоне, но вот целиком, что он показал:

```
C:\Users\пользователь\Desktop\1\rpatool -x C:\Users\пользователь\Desktop\1\images.rpa -o C:\Users\пользователь\Desktop\ddlc-files\images

File "< stdin >", line 1
C:\Users\пользователь\Desktop\1\rpatool -x C:\Users\пользователь\Desktop\1\images.rpa -o C:\Users\пользователь\Desktop\ddlc-files\images

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: А какая именно ошибка? Добавьте в вопрос через кнопку `править` текст ошибки

Comment: Конечно, ничего не понятно в моем вопросе, но я добавил все, что смог. Не шарю в питоне совсем :D

Comment: код тоже нужен .

Comment: Вам стоит отправить багрепорт автору [rpatool](https://github.com/Shizmob/rpatool/issues).